# get URL from wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I capture some packet of an application to get the URL when connects the application. The packet says:

21  11.971007   10.0.2.15   209.85.169.132  HTTP    GET /ig/proxy?max_age=3600&source=mofe&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsports.apis.google.com%2Fsportsapi%3FleagueId%3Ditla1%26qtype%3Dstandings HTTP/1.1

UP]m1zHPfGET /ig/proxy?max_age=3600&source=mofe&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsports.apis.google.com%2Fsportsapi%3FleagueId%3Ditla1%26qtype%3Dstandings HTTP/1.1
Host: scoreboard.gmodules.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)

I'm trying to go to these URL but it says me: Not Found:
http://scoreboard.gmodules.com/ig/proxy?max_age=3600&source=mofe&url=http://sports.apis.google.com/sportsapi?leagueId=itla1&qtype=standings

Could you help me please?
Many thanks and sorry for my english!

Answer (score 0):

You should check, whether Referer or WWW-Authenticate headers present in original message.
The gateway at gmodules.com could possibly reject requests coming without proper headers set.